# moment.js cannot convert two strings to one

Tags: datetime, datepicker, momentjs

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class DateTimeFormat {
    format(date, time) {
        alert(date);

        return moment(date + 'T' + time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    }
}
```

'Date' can come through as a string 'DD/MM/YYYY' (from the DB on load), or a date object from the calander (`this.value = $('.input-group.date', this.element).datepicker('getUTCDate');`) datepicker is used within a custom element.

DateTimeFormat is used like this:

```
            .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) })
                .if(() => {
                    return this.baseContent.ValidFromDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidFromTime !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToTime !== null })
                    .passes( () => { return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime) })
                    .withMessage('< Valid To')
                .endIf()
```

I have tried: 
moment.(date) - Fails invalid date
moment.utc(date) - Fails invalid date

I don't know whether I need to add a try catch in? I.e try and convert from a date object, if it falls within the catch it then must be a string from a db etc?

Using the information below from @VicenzoC I have added an if statement

```
var dateFormatted;

if (typeof(date) === 'string')
{
    dateFormatted = date;
}
else
{
    // Must be an object from a calendar etc
    alert(date);
    dateFormatted = moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    alert(dateFormatted);
}

return moment(date + 'T' + time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

First alert -

[image]

Second alert -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your `.datepicker('getUTCDate')` returns a `Date` object, in this case you can parse it into `moment` object just using [`moment(Date);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/)

```
this.value = $('.input-group.date', this.element).datepicker('getUTCDate');
var momentObj = moment(this.value);
```

If you have a string you can parse it using:

- [`moment(String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) if it is in one of ISO 8601 supported formats (e.g. `20130208T080910`)
- [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) passing your custom format as second parameter.
- [`moment(String, String[]);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) if you have to handle multiple formats.

Once you have a `moment` object you can use the [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method if you need to display your date in a custom format.

Comment: Thanks @VicenzoC, when the page first loads the data is pulled from a db  and therefore comes out like 'DD/MM/YYYY' only when its been selected from the calendar does it return a date object. Am I best doing something like a try/catch statement?

Comment: @VicenzoC - Updated my question as I don't think I was explaining it correctly.

Comment: @ClareBarrington maybe you can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to determine your input variable type and then call moment appropriate parsing function.

Comment: Thanks @VicenzoC. I've updated my code to use a if statement, and updated my question

Comment: Thanks for you help @VicenzoC

Answer (score 0):

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class DateTimeFormat {
    format(date, time) {

        var dateFormatted;

        if (typeof(date) === 'string')
        {
            dateFormatted = date;
        }
        else
        {
            // Must be an object from a calendar etc
            dateFormatted = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        }

        return moment(dateFormatted + 'T' + time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    }
}
```

This is the final code, I first determine the typeof (thanks again @VicenzoC for pointing me in that direction) then I handle the date part within the if statement.